# Facebook getAccessToken does not work

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, access-token

I followed the documentation to write my login_callback.php
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
```

But my code will be stuck at this line:

```
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
```

The code just stop and do not jump to catching exception.
Yet, I got [This authorization code has been used] after I refreshed the page.

Comment: You are only catching two very specific exceptions - so if a different one occurs, your code does not catch it, and that will eventually result in a fatal error. You should always do a `catch (Exception $e)` at the very end, to catch _all_ general exceptions that have not been caught by the more specific catch attempts before.

Comment: That's it! Thank a lot! :D
It was related to the date timezone setting.